# disable second spinner click till 1st spinner get its value : android

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have a program in android where spinner gets the data dynamically from rest services. what i want to achieve is when the first spinner loads its value, the selected value loads the value of 2nd and third spinner. i want to disable the click of 2nd and third spinner till the spinner gets populated are loaded in all the spinner.
I call the function of populating 2nd & 3rd spinner in the end of the program.

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner1() 
{
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String strEmployeeID="";
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
strEmployeeID = value;
}
JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
try
{
login.put("EmployeeID",strEmployeeID);
//login.put("Password", etCountry.getText().toString());
JSONObject finaldata = new JSONObject();
finaldata.put("ProjectRequest", login);
final ConnectToServer connect = new ConnectToServer();
connect.extConnectToServer(HourlyEntry.this,new ConnectToServer.Callback() 
{
public void callFinished(String result)
{
// Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
JSONObject resp = null;
try 
{
resp = new JSONObject(result);
// Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
JSONObject Login1Result = resp.getJSONObject("ProjectResult");
JSONArray DepartmentDetails = Login1Result.getJSONArray("ProjectDetails");
// String strMessage = Login1Result.getString("message");
// Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Login1Result.getString("ProjectDetails"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
if (!Login1Result.getString("ProjectDetails").equalsIgnoreCase("null")) 
{
//JSONArray DepartmentDetails = Login1Result.getJSONArray("ProjectDetails");

m_Project_list = new ArrayList<String>();
m_projectID_list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < DepartmentDetails.length(); i++) 
{
JSONObject m_DepartmentDetails = DepartmentDetails.getJSONObject(i);
// Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),m_DepartmentDetails.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (!m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectName").equalsIgnoreCase("null")&& !m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectName").equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
{
// list.add(m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectName"));
m_Project_list.add(m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectName"));
// Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (!m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectID").equalsIgnoreCase("null")&& !m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectID").equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
{
m_projectID_list.add(m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectID"));
//Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectID"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String strProjectID="";
String item2 =  m_DepartmentDetails.getString("ProjectID");
strProjectID = item2;
}
}
}
s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.spin,m_Project_list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(adapter);
if (m_projectID_list.contains(m_ProjectID)) 
{
s1.setSelection(m_projectID_list.indexOf(m_ProjectID));
}
}
catch (final JSONException e)
{
}
}
}, "http://aapna.azurewebsites.net/Service1/Project", finaldata,
"POST");
connect.execute(finaldata);
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
int position, long id) {
// On selecting a spinner item
final String item1 = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
final String SelectedProjectID = m_projectID_list.get(s1.getSelectedItemPosition());
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//  SelectedProjectID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  Showing selected spinner item
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//  "Selected  : " + item1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
s2.setClickable(false); 
s3.setClickable(false);
addItemsOnSpinner2(SelectedProjectID);
s2.setClickable(true);
addItemsOnSpinner3(SelectedProjectID);
s3.setClickable(true);
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
}
catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: PLease help. I need to fix this by today

Comment: in the onItemSelectedListener of the firstSpinner enable the second spinner, and in the onItemSelected of the second spinner enable the third spinner.

Comment: ya i know that would do. but it takes few seconds to load and change data if i click when the data is still loading it give sme a balnk spinner. which i dont want

Comment: hmm that would happen unless you deal with setVisibility then

Comment: so is there any way to achieve this. i dont want to show the annoying progress dialog for each spinner.

Comment: try hariharan's answer

Comment: ya i tried that but if the selected value is the position zero itself i canoot use the other two spinner. all my spinners contain lot of values. setting at zero the spinners wont be enabled to change the value of 2nd and third spinner

Comment: you have a list of values correct?? add at the position 0 a dummy value say select, then the position 0 funda might work correct ??

Comment: Ya but that would be j.tech as we call it in india. the list of value I get is from the .net Api which interacts with database. each employee gets certain projects. Do you think it would be a good idea to add a dummy value ?

Comment: its just a select option you are adding, i dont think theres any harm to it.. :).. you have a valid reason to explain i am sure .. so u can justify your cause.

Comment: i know adding would help. but the problem was not that. problem is if i select any value in spinner one , the spinner 2 and 3takes  some time to load the values and if i click the spinners during that process i get null value in spinners.

Comment: Did it from that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I got is to use delay function to solve this kind of spinner as told to me by hariharan.

ADD these two statements in spinner 1 function

```
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                            int position, long id)
                    {
                        // On selecting a spinner item

                        final String item1 = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                        final String SelectedProjectID = m_projectID_list.get(s1.getSelectedItemPosition());


                         s2.setEnabled(false);
                         s3.setEnabled(false);


                               addItemsOnSpinner2(SelectedProjectID);

                               addItemsOnSpinner3(SelectedProjectID);
                               delay1();

//                      



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                    {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
            });
```

then use the below function

```
 public void delay1()
    {
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                  s2.setEnabled(true);
                 s3.setEnabled(true);
              }

        }, 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change your **first element** from **m_Project_list ArrayList as Select**

And after **user selecting spinner** you can do other operation below codes inside `onCreate`

**Code**

```
s1.setSelection(0);
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(pos == 0){
                s2.setEnabled(false);
                s3.setEnabled(false);
           }
           else{
               // do something
               addItemsOnSpinner2(SelectedProjectID);
               s2.setEnabled(true);
               addItemsOnSpinner3(SelectedProjectID);
               s3.setEnabled(true);
           }
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

**EDIT**

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("==========","  handler == > "); 

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }, 5000);
```

Comment: What i am trying to ask is when i change the value of first spinner the value changes of 2nd and 3rd respectively. but it takes time to change but if i click when the processing is still going on it return a 2nd spinner. i have to press back and click again

Comment: ok sorry, now i understand . but what if the spinner zero value is the one i want to choose. then can i use the other two spinners?

Comment: Is there a way i can freeze the enable state for few seconds.

Comment: @user3433054 set timer schedule and enable/disable it.

Comment: @user3433054 if you choose one position s2,s3 spinner will populate. And you can use it.

Comment: can u tell how to set time scheduler

Comment: @user3433054 or use a handler with postDelayed method.

Comment: @user3433054 Initilly `s2.setEnabled(false);` for both spinner and inside run() enable it `s2.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: @user3433054 did you try my ans. did you get result.